# Redis move from AOF to RDB

Tags: redis

We have a Redis server running with the default configuration but AOF enabled.
We want to disable AOF, and instead use RDB only, for performance reasons.

If we restart the Redis instance with `--appendonly no` all keys are lost. Restarting again with `--appendonly yes` thankfully returns our data to us.

The redis docs show [how to go from RDB to AOF](https://redis.io/topics/persistence#how-i-can-switch-to-aof-if-i39m-currently-using-dumprdb-snapshots), but what is the correct way to migrate from AOF to RDB?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following works:

```
redis-cli set appendonly no
redis-cli SAVE
```

and then the server can be safely restarted and the new data is available.
Changing the appendonly param using the CLI is important, changes should be made to the running system rather than restarting it with new values.

Tested on an inactive redis instance, unsure how this approach handles data loss if the instance is being actively used.